# Exercise for determining a function

Tags: calculus

> What is the function that verifies all this conditions:
>
> $f:\mathbb{R}\backslash{1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
>
> $f''(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$
>
> $f(0)=0$
>
> $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f'(x) = 1$
>
> $f(e+1)=0$
>
> $f'(0)=0$

My attempt:

The first thing I did was to find the integral of $f''(x)$ which is:

$f''(x)= \frac{1}{1-x}+C$

(C is an arbitrary constant).

Well but now I can't find a constant because if

$\lim_{x\to+\infty} f'(x) = 1$

then $C=1$

but if  $f'(0)=0$

then $C=-1$

Is this exercise possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this exercise is possible.

You don't necessarily have the same constant on $]-\infty,1[$ and on $]1,+\infty[$.

In your case, it looks like you have $C=1$ on $]1,+\infty[$ and $C=-1$ on  $]-\infty,1[$. You should be able to continue, and keep in mind that it is also true for your second integration.